Why Permission denied for symbolic link with rw permission
I am using Truenas scale and assigning permission. I am trying to create a symbolic link under the user's home file. The user got r-x permission for the file but still cannot cd into the directory and the symbolic link.
root@truenas[/mnt/Pool1]# getfacl directories
# file: directories
# owner: jh
# group: jh
user::rwx
user:user:r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---

'User' should get all the permissions needed to read the file, but it cannot be read from the link or the path.
User@truenas:~$ cd '/mnt/Pool1/directories'
-bash: cd: /mnt/Pool1/directories: Permission denied

User@truenas:~/directories$ cd directories
-bash: cd: directories: Permission denied

Why does this happen?

The "permissions" on a link don't matter, only the permissions on the target. Linux doesn't do permissions on links.

/mnt/ ?  did you mount it from somewhere ? Did you mount it with read+write&x perm??
